# Make onmousedown, onmousemove, onmouseup work on touch devices

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, touch-event

I have this snippet which draws lots of random opacity/size circles which is configured to work with mouse events. However when I try changing el.onmousedown, el.onmousemove and el.onmouseup to el.ontouchstart, el.ontouchmove and el.ontouchend respectively then it doesn't work at all on touch devices (responsive mode) or normal mode. I need to somehow change the mouse events to touch events and make it work. I'm not sure why changing them as I outlined above didn't work. I would appreciate any help, thanks! Code snippet below.

```
function waterColour( e ) {
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
  var isDrawing, points = [ ], radius = 15;

  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  if (!ctx.fillstyle) {
   ctx.fillStyle = toolColor;
  } else {
   ctx.fillstyle = ctx.fillstyle;
  }


  el.onmousedown = function(e) {
   isDrawing = true;
   points.push({
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY,
    radius: getRandomInt(30, 40),
    opacity: Math.random() * (0.35 - 0.15) + 0.15,
    fillColour: ctx.fillstyle
  });

 };
 el.onmousemove = function(e) {
   if (!isDrawing) return;
   points.push({
     x: e.clientX,
     y: e.clientY,
     radius: getRandomInt(30, 40),
     opacity: Math.random() * (0.35 - 0.15) + 0.15,
     fillColour: ctx.fillstyle
   });

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.globalAlpha = points[i].opacity;

     ctx.arc(
       points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].radius,
       false, Math.PI * 2, false);
     ctx.fill();
   }
 };
 el.onmouseup = function() {
   isDrawing = false;

 }
}
```

Comment: **Your snippet is not working**. As for your question you may use the same function for the "mousedown" & the "touchstart" events; the same function for the "mousemove" & "touchmove" events and the same function for 
"mouseup","touchend" & "mouseout". Also: you have only one mouse event but you may have several touches. For example you have event.clientX for mouse events & event.touches[0].clientX for a touch event.

Comment: It probably isn't working for you because you don't have the other JS, HTML and CSS because it works for me. The only problem is it only works with a mouse and when I try touch it doesn't draw anything but with console.log I can see it's still executing everything which is very strange.

Comment: In this case, if you need help,  you should consider updating your question and post a working example.

Comment: I solved it. It involved adding touch event listeners in the place of the mouse functions. I also had to change the e.clientX/e.clientY to event.touches[0].pageX/event.touches[0].pageY.